# Environment.Exit hangs

Tags: c#, exit, freeze

In C#, what would cause Environment.Exit(1) to hang? I'm calling my program from the command line, and it ends up with a blinking cursor on a blank line. Typing doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you doing multi-threading or spawning child processes?  Not sure if that should effect it or not, but it might be a place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

The [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) doesn't hang the application, on the contrary, it terminates it instantly:

> Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

There is something else causing your Console application to hang, but we can't guess what is the issue without you adding some code.